# Feasibility of using Apache Spark when having multiple Java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, apache-spark

I am working on a Java application in which we have multiple threads around 450. The size of the thread pool is 25. The task of each thread is to call 8 to 9 Web services, get the response, parse the response XML and store the extracted data into the database. A total number of rows that go into database table having 10 to 12 columns are around 30000.

Since there is a lot of parallel processing here, should we introduce Apache Spark for this scenario? Will it be extra overhead for maintaining Apache spark cluster and all? How can we divide the problem here to put it as a driver program for Apache Spark?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite broad question, but you should follow this questions:

- is your task manipulating data? It may get data, manipulate and save or rely on side-effects
- what is your workload? Is only one JVM on one computer enough to process data?

If you have yes in first question and no in the second, then you can consider using Spark.

The fact you must now is that Spark:

- is designed to manipulate, aggregate, process data
- is for distributed computing,

so if you don't use those features, use for example Akka for easy parallel processing, even in distributed manner. Spark will be good solution for data analysis, machine learning, OLAP queries and graph processing

Comment: It takes around 1 hour minutes to complete all tasks currently with Java multi-threading. And data manipulation is not up to that much extent.